# JSP to Java Data transfer

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, xml, jsp

I am trying to build a webpage where I input data, it goes to a page that displays the data and asks for confirmation, and then it submits the data to a SQL database. It works up until the second submission to the database, there it submits NULL values into the db. Here is the following code

Index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" action="index1.jsp" method="post" class="decor">
      <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
      <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="form-inner">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        
        <input type="text" name = "First" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="Id" placeholder="ID">
        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <button  type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>

      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index1.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Confirm</title>


</head>
<body>


<h1>Confirm for submission</h1>
    <%
    
    String id = request.getParameter("Id");
    String first = request.getParameter("First");
    String last = request.getParameter("Last");
    String email = request.getParameter("Email");
    String phone = request.getParameter("Phone");
        
    %>
<table border="1">
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td>ID : </td>
    <td><%=id %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Name : </td>
    <td><%=first %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name : </td>
    <td><%=last %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email : </td>
    <td><%=email %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone : </td>
    <td><%=phone %></td>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>

 <form target="_blank" name="myform" action="Register" method="post" class="decor">
        <div>   
        <button  type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>

        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In index1.jsp you do not have any fields in your `form` - what do you expect to be posted?

Comment: your form is empty and you're also not gathering the submitted values anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I reestablished new fields using the pulled data like this

```
String name2 = <%=last %>;
```

Thanks anyway